# Changing JPanel Size in my JFrame

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

What i want is my timer buttons to be on the bottom with minimal space for them, i dont want them to take half of the frame, but i dont know how to resize the panel within the frame. Help would be appreciated and if someone could proof read it too that would be nice.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SudokuPanel extends JFrame {

    public final int SQUARE_COUNT = 9;
    public Squares [] squares = new Squares[SQUARE_COUNT];


    public SudokuPanel(){

        super("Sudoku");
        setSize(600,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));


        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));
        for(int i=0; i<SQUARE_COUNT; i++){
            squares[i] = new Squares();
            panel.add(squares[i]);
        }

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        JButton start = new JButton();
        JButton stop = new JButton();

        start = new JButton("Start Timer");
        stop = new JButton("Stop Timer");

        panel2.add(start);
        panel2.add(stop);

        add(panel);
        add(panel2);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        JMenuItem newDifficulty = new JMenuItem("Select New Difficulty");
        menu.add(newDifficulty);

        JMenuItem reset = new JMenuItem("Reset");
        menu.add(reset);

        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        menu.add(exit);

        class newDifficultyaction implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                dispose();
                Level select = new Level(); 
            }
        }

        class exitaction implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        newDifficulty.addActionListener(new newDifficultyaction());
        exit.addActionListener(new exitaction());

        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't run your code since you're using some classes not included. To put your buttons taking up minimal space at the bottom of the panel, I'd suggest using a [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for the Frame.

So instead of GridLayout, use:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Then add panel2 with the buttons to the bottom of the frame:

```
add(panel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Since `panel` is the main component, you'll want that to take up most of the space, so position it center:

```
add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: +1, but the default layout manager for a `JFrame` is the `BorderLayout`, so just delete the `setLayout( new GridLayout(...) )` statement.